# Android: music volume stays low after audio focus gained

Tags: android, audio, volume

In my player app (on `Android 6.0`)  the music volume (of my own player, not the media player api) remains low/ ducked after the audio focus returns to the app.

I'm not ducking anything myself when the audio focus gets lost, just stopping and resuming the playback on the respective event types `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` / `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS` of my `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` implementation.

I have already tried to explicitly set the stream_music volume to max or to call

```
adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
```

but with no success. My app needs to be restarted then the volume level is normal again.

Whereas the Android media player behaves correctly, it raises the volume after a phone call is finished. It is just with my app.

How can I force returning to normal volume programatically ?